# Android Softkeyboard Code list

Tags: java, android, xml, android-softkeyboard

is there a list of possible android codes out there?

I'm using the Android IME to create a custom softkeyboard.
My current XML file looks like this:

```
<Row>
    <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4" />
    <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5"  />
    <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6"  />
    </Row>
<Row>
```

Currently my keyboard works but I want to know what kind of keycodes I can use.

So my question is, where can I get a list of codes I can use for my softkeyboard. I only found some Keycodes from the android [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_F5) but they dont work.

I hope you guys can help me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like [Generic.kl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cd92588/data/keyboards/Generic.kl)

You can also find it in "/system/usr/keylayout/", there are a loot of *.kl file.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but the values in the link unfortunately didn't match my current xml

Comment: @user5985727 Did you mean convert "key 2     1" to "<Key android:codes="2" android:keyLabel="1" />" or something?